# Porque utilizar chunk en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algoritmos, lógica

Tengo una gran cantidad de datos retornados por una consulta, 3297387229 datos para ser exactos.

En `laravel` me recomiendan utilizar chunk para recorrer los datos, ya que los recorro de forma "normal", asi:

```
<div class="row">
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Un foreach para recorrer todos los datos, `chunk` en cambio parte el collection en pequeños `arrays` para posterior recorrerlos uno a uno, asi:

```
@foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($chunk as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Entonces

> 1.-Cual es la diferencia entre ambos si los dos recorren la misma cantidad de datos?
>   2.-Chunk siempre tendrá mas ciclos por tener dos `for`, ¿Porque utilizarlo?

Answer (score 3):

El método `chunk`<sup>1</sup> genera un rompimiento de los datos retornados en una colección; es decir:

```
$datos = collect(["uno", "beta", "tres", "no", "siete"]);
```

Cuando le indicamos a `chunk` que los recorra de este modo:

```
$segmentos = $datos->chunk(2);
```

Le estamos diciendo que genere una salida de 3 colecciones con este aspecto:

1. `["uno", "beta"]`
2. `["tres", "no"]`
3. `["siete"]`

Es decir en vez de retornar toda la data en una sola colección, me retorno todos los datos pero rompe todo el contenido en múltiples fragmentos.

<sup>2</sup> Retomo el [ejemplo que di en otra pregunta para el caso de Eloquent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290619/extraer-valores-ramdon-en-base-de-datos-con-mas-de-8m-de-registros-en-laravel/290642#290642) donde para obtener datos de forma aleatoria de una base de datos con mas de 100000 registros el método `chunk` fue utilizado para romper la colección en grupos mas pequeños de 100 registros, así aunque los consulta todos los procesa por bloques pequeños y no como uno solo.

Por ejemplo en esta consulta:

```
$data = Modelo::inRandomOrder()
                 ->take(25000)
                 ->get()
                 ->chunk(100);
```

Le indico que de los mas de 100000 registros solo tome 25000 y que de esos mismos los agrupe para ir recuperándolos de 100 en 100, *para facilitar el trabajo y la carga por las consultas escritas*

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[Método `chunk` de la clase `Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk) del cual me base para construir el primer ejemplo.
- <sup>2</sup>[Método chunk en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#chunking-results)

Answer (score 2):

> En laravel me recomiendan utilizar chunk para recorrer los datos

En realidad a este [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-chunk) no lo recomiendan porque la colección tenga una gran cantidad de datos, solo dice:

> Este método es especialmente útil en [vistas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) cuando se trabaja con un sistema de cuadrícula como [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Y ahí va con el ejemplo:

> Imagine que tiene una colección de modelos Eloquent que desea mostrar en una cuadrícula:

```php
@foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($chunk as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Y tú dices

> los recorro de forma "normal", asi:

```php
<div class="row">
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

> 1.-Cual es la diferencia entre ambos si los dos recorren la misma cantidad de datos?

La diferencia es el html resultante, ya que para el caso del ejemplo con `chunk`, el resultante sería

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre ...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre ...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre ...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 3297387229</div>
</div>
```

y para el caso sin `chunk`, el resultante sería

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre ...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">Nombre 3297387229</div>
</div>
```

> 2.-Chunk siempre tendrá mas ciclos por tener dos for, ¿Porque utilizarlo?

Sí, es cierto, tendrá más ciclos for y mas `<div class="row">`. Creo que para el caso, solo depende de como quieres que se vea tu grilla.

Claro que al decir que la colección que manejas tiene 3297387229 elementos, llama la atención pues por cuestiones de memoria, tranferencia en la red, etc, sería mejor paginarlos o ver la manera de trabajar con eso de manera segmentada al momento de la consulta a BD.